# Facing error in C# Generics Reference type constraint:'T' does not contain a definition for 'FooMethod'

Tags: c#, generics, reference

```
public  class Foo {
    public Foo ThisX { get; set; }
    public Foo ThisY { get; set; }

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Foo(Foo x, Foo y) {
        ThisX = x;
        ThisY = y;
    }

    public void FooMethod(Foo ob) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hiiiii\t" + ob); 
    }
}

public class Gen<T> where T : class {
    T obj;

    public Gen() {
    }

    public Gen(T x,T y) {
        Console.WriteLine("Gen(T x,T y)\t" + x.GetType().Name + " " + y.GetType().Name);// + " " + obj.GetType().Name);
    }

    public void Display(T ob) {
        obj = ob;
        Console.WriteLine("Display  " + ob.GetType().Name + " " + obj.GetType().Name);
        obj.FooMethod(obj);
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Gen<Foo> m = new Gen<Foo>();

        Foo ob1 = new Foo();
        Foo ob2 = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine("Main " + m.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("Main " + ob1.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Gen<Foo> n = new Gen<Foo>(ob1, ob2);
        Console.WriteLine();        
        m.Display(ob1);
    }
}
```

The line "`obj.FooMethod(obj)`" giving an error saying 
"'T' does not contain a definition for 'FooMethod' and no extension
 method 'FooMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be
 found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to format your code samples, making sure they look like the kind of code *you'd* want to see if you were reading the post. Next, please explain why you'd expect `obj.FooMethod(obj)` to work, given that within `Gen<T>`, `T` could be *any* type. Imagine that I'd created a `Gen<string>` for example - what would you expect `Display` to do in that case?

Comment: Why are you using generics here anyway?

Comment: i learning generics, i am trying to call  'FooMethod' through "Display". what is the use of reference type constraint if  it takes arguments of type class and do not support methods of that class.

Comment: You either need to *cast* or give the generic type's varable a *constraint* on ``Foe`` before getting access to ``Foo``s methods and fields.

Comment: the type of object in "Display" is "Foo" but why it is not possible to call "FooMethod"?

Comment: "The type of object in "Display" is "Foo". No it's not, all you've constrained T to is class. That means that Gen<String> or Gen<DataSet> could be created, and those don't implement a FooMethod(Foo object) method. So T (in Gen) has to be constrained to be a class that implements the method, either by specifying the class constraint or creating an interface and constraining to that. Check the answers below on how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in the type constraint you gave in Gen

```
public class Gen<T> where T:class
```

At this point you are telling the compiler that T is going to be *at least* a class at the bare minimum.  It may do more, but if definitely won't do less.  In your definition you are telling the compiler that T is at least a class.  A class is a generic thing that anyone can create which can do anything, but at its very least, it does nothing.  The compiler understands the later and assumes that the bare minimum is an empty class as it can't guarantee a method, property, field, etc is always going to be there.

To get this to work we'll need to help the compiler a little bit with understanding what we want it to deal with.  Your implementation of T has a common defintion, FooMethod.  What happens inside of FooMethod? We don't care, and Gen doesn't care, we just want to execute it.  What needs to happen is an abstract base class or an interface should be introduced for Gen to use as a constraint for T that way we *at least* have this method defined.  After that we are going to implement this abstract base class (or interface) so that the compiler understands that we have a FooMethod defined.

The finalized code is below:

```
//abstract class to establish the presence of FooMethod, but not the functionality
public abstract class FooBase {
    public abstract void FooMethod(FooBase obj);
}

//Implement FooBase so that Foo is guaranteed to have a FooMethod implementation
public class Foo : FooBase
{

    public Foo()
    {
    }
    public Foo(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        ThisX = x;
        ThisY = y;
    }

    public Foo ThisX { get; set; }
    public Foo ThisY { get; set; }

    //Override FooMethod so that it can do whatever Foo needs it to do
    public override void FooMethod(FooBase ob)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hiiiii\t" + ob);

    }

}

public class Gen<T> where T : FooBase
{

    T obj;

    public Gen()
    {


    }
    public Gen(T x, T y)
    {



        Console.WriteLine("Gen(T x,T y)\t" + x.GetType().Name.ToString() + " " + y.GetType().Name.ToString());//+" "+obj.GetType().Name.ToString());

    }

    public void Display(T ob)
    {
        obj = ob;
        Console.WriteLine("Display  " + ob.GetType().Name.ToString() + " " + obj.GetType().Name.ToString());

        //Fire the objests implementation of FooBase.FooMethod(FooBase obj)
        obj.FooMethod(obj);
    }

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Gen<Foo> m = new Gen<Foo>();

        Foo ob1 = new Foo();
        Foo ob2 = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine("Main " + m.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("Main " + ob1.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Gen<Foo> n = new Gen<Foo>(ob1, ob2);
        Console.WriteLine();
        m.Display(ob1);

        //To stop the console
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: this is base class constraint

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you're having is that the method FooMethod isn't a known method of class, so the generic Gen class is trying to call FooMethod within any class and failing. To get round this, the T type in Gen *has* to own a signature identical to the obj.FooMethod(obj); that is called from Gen

You can make this work in 2 ways, depending on what you're trying to acheive. If the Foo class is a base class, then the declaration for the Gen class to use the base class instead of class so:

```
public class Gen<T> where T:Foo
{

}
```

Or make an interface for Foo to implement:

```
public interface IFoo<T>
{
    public void FooMethod(T ob)
    {
    }
}

class Foo : IFoo<Foo>
{
}
```

And tell your Gen class to use only classes that implement that interface:

```
public class Gen<T> where T:IFoo
{

}
```